# Controllers in seperate assembly and getting a 'The controller for path "/controllerName/" was not found or does not implement IController.' error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am doing some work on a project and I am trying to get my development environment working. The project is written in ASP.net MVC 2. I have ASP.net MVC 3 installed. The controllers have been moved to a seperate project that is namespaced ProjectName.Web.Controllers. All of the controllers inherit from System.Web.MVC.Controller. When I try to hit a controller I get the following:

```
[HttpException]: The controller for path '/controllerName'; was not found or does not implement IController.
```

If I make a controllers folder in the web project that contains the views, copy all the controllers there and recompile, it works fine.

Comment: Everyone else using the project is using the original MVC 2 that they installed months ago and they all work fine. I am using MVC 3 and I have installed it on two machines and it hasn't worked on either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem in revisiting this today. The solution was created on a machine that did not have the latest version of ASP.Net MVC on it. It only had version 2 and worked just fine. My machine has version 3 and didn't work. Turns out the controller project was referencing the version 3 assembly on my machine and the version 2 on the original machine. The reference looked like the following:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\Web\bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Since the web project is using version 2 of ASP.Net MVC that is why I was getting the error that the controller didn't implement IController, it was looking for IController in version 2 not version 3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new project namespace into the DefaultNamespaces collection on the current ControllerBuilder

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("ProjectName.Web.Controllers");
```

Comment: I have added that line to the Application_Start method of the Global.asax.cs and I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you moved all the controllers in a separate project. Did you reference this project in your ASP.NET MVC application? Is the resulting assembly present in the `bin` folder of the site?

Comment: Yes the project is referenced and the dll is in the bin folder. I will try to add more detail to the question. Thanks